# Maven Configuration in azure-devops

Tags: maven, azure-devops

I have installed maven 3.6.3 on ubuntu 18.04 azure hosted agent. How can I setup a MAVEN_HOME and path in Microsoft hosted agent and how can I edit settings.xml

I added below parameters in azure-pipelines.yml (under maven task)
mavenVersionOption: 'Path'
mavenDirectory: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/maven/apache-maven-3.6.3'
mavenSetM2Home: true

What other configurations do I need to do here and how can I add the contents in settings.xml.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You can create your own `settings.xml` and reference it in your pipeline by `mvn clean package -s settings.xml`

Comment: Glad to hear it, I also shared it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own settings.xml which has all custom configs and reference it in your pipeline by calling `mvn clean package -s settings.xml`